# In Which class should I put a method for comparison?

Tags: java, class, methods, comparison

Let's say I have a class called myClass. I want to have a method which compares instances of myClass to see if one object of myCLass is "greater than" another object of myClass. 
**Should this method be put inside the myClass class?** 
Intuitively, this seems to be wrong because the 'compare' method isn't actually an action that should is carried out by either of the objects. (For example, when two numbers are compared, the numbers don't compare themselves.. WE, the humans, compare the numbers and determine the result of the comparison.. )

Comment: It is a waste to make a new class to add a comparing method. It actually makes sense to use the same class. For example, if you want to compare a "hammer" with another "hammer", you wouldn't ask an "apple" to compare it for you. You would pick up one, and observe differences from the other one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it 2 ways:

1. Have a normal `compareTo()` method that compares the current instance of the object against another instance, e.g.

   `obj1.compareTo(obj2)`
2. Have a static method that belongs to the `myClass` class that compares 2 object instances, e.g.

   `myClass.compareObjects(obj1, obj2)`

Comment: Don't forget that MyClass should implement Comparable<MyClass> if you're going with option 1!